# Thumbnail preview for HLS using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, thumbnails, hls, thumbnail-generator

I have a question about converting an mp4 file to HLS. I would also like to include the first frame of each ts chunk as a thumbnail in the m3u8 file. Is it possible to accomplish this using a single command in ffmpeg? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Next time posting please also include the actual command you're using. This will make it easier to provide a practicable answer.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way: After you've created the `.ts` files, loop over them (e.g. with a shell script), and use ffmpeg to extract the first frame for each, e.g.:

```
ffmpeg -i segment01.ts -frames:v 1 -s 320x240 thumbnail01.png
```

Doing this in parallel will certainly speed up things, e.g. with [`parallel`](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/):

```
parallel echo ffmpeg -i {} -frames:v 1 -s 320x240 {.}.png ::: *.ts
```

To do this directly from the HLS command, you need to generate another video stream. Assuming you have this basic video-only HLS generation command (which I lazily adapted from [here](https://ottverse.com/hls-packaging-using-ffmpeg-live-vod/)):

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i testsrc=duration=10:rate=24:size=1920x1080 \
  -filter_complex \
  "[0:v]split=3[v1][v2][v3]; \
  [v1]copy[v1out];[v2]scale=w=1280:h=720[v2out];[v3]scale=w=640:h=360[v3out]" \
  -map "[v1out]" -c:v:0 libx264 -b:v:0 5M -maxrate:v:0 5M -minrate:v:0 5M -bufsize:v:0 10M -g 48 -sc_threshold 0 -keyint_min 48 \
  -map "[v2out]" -c:v:1 libx264 -b:v:1 3M -maxrate:v:1 3M -minrate:v:1 3M -bufsize:v:1 3M -g 48 -sc_threshold 0 -keyint_min 48 \
  -map "[v3out]" -c:v:2 libx264 -b:v:2 1M -maxrate:v:2 1M -minrate:v:2 1M -bufsize:v:2 1M -g 48 -sc_threshold 0 -keyint_min 48 \
  -f hls \
  -hls_time 2 \
  -hls_playlist_type vod \
  -hls_flags independent_segments \
  -hls_segment_type mpegts \
  -hls_segment_filename stream_%v/segment_%02d.ts \
  -master_pl_name master.m3u8 \
  -var_stream_map "v:0 v:1 v:2" stream_%v.m3u8
```

You need to add one more video stream containing just the thumbnails. We increase the number of splits and add one more filter chain that scales the thumbnails down and decreases their framerate to one thumbnail every 2 seconds (i.e., 0.5fps, since 2s is also the duration of the segments):

```
ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=duration=10:rate=24:size=1920x1080 \
  -filter_complex \
  "[0:v]split=4[v1][v2][v3][thumbs]; \
  [v1]copy[v1out];[v2]scale=w=1280:h=720[v2out];[v3]scale=w=640:h=360[v3out];[thumbs]scale=w=428:h=240,fps=fps=0.5[thumbsout]" \
  -map "[v1out]" -c:v:0 libx264 -b:v:0 5M -maxrate:v:0 5M -minrate:v:0 5M -bufsize:v:0 10M -g 48 -sc_threshold 0 -keyint_min 48 \
  -map "[v2out]" -c:v:1 libx264 -b:v:1 3M -maxrate:v:1 3M -minrate:v:1 3M -bufsize:v:1 3M -g 48 -sc_threshold 0 -keyint_min 48 \
  -map "[v3out]" -c:v:2 libx264 -b:v:2 1M -maxrate:v:2 1M -minrate:v:2 1M -bufsize:v:2 1M -g 48 -sc_threshold 0 -keyint_min 48 \
    -f hls \
    -hls_time 2 \
    -hls_playlist_type vod \
    -hls_flags independent_segments \
    -hls_segment_type mpegts \
    -hls_segment_filename stream_%v/segment_%02d.ts \
    -master_pl_name master.m3u8 \
    -var_stream_map "v:0 v:1 v:2" \
    stream_%v.m3u8 \
  -map "[thumbsout]" \
    -c:v:3 png \
    -vsync:v:3 vfr \
    -f image2 \
    thumbs_%03d.png
```

This will generate the thumbnails in parallel to the HLS stream.